# GWT project debug crash

Tags: eclipse, gwt, gecko

I build my GWT project successfully. After dubug when tried to run the generated URL in browser the following error comes.

```
[ERROR] The value gecko was not previously defined. 
[ERROR] Line 35: Unexpected exception while processing element 'set-property'
```

the set property is defined as :

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="ie6,ie8,safari,opera" />
```

Must be some silly mistake please point out.

other error reported in console are:

```
[ERROR] Failure while parsing XML
[ERROR] Unexpected error while processing XML
```

Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add gecko1_8 for Firefox support.

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="gecko1_8" />
```

Comment: FYI, this tells the GWT compiler to only compile for gecko browsers. If you remove `<set-property name="user.agent" value="..." />` tag altogether, it will compile for all versions. One major benefit of having this tag is that it speeds up your compilation time.